# sed remove a line matching a pattern if not after another matching pattern

Tags: linux, awk, sed

The file contents should be like this:

```
foo
foobar
bar
```

foo or foobar can exist alone. But bar must be after foo and can't occur without foo. So any occurrences of bar without foo, I want to delete.

For my use case (the issue), bar was always coming before foo once and after foo once.

```
bar
...
foo
foobar
bar
```

So I used `grep` to find the number of occurrences and `sed` to delete the 1st occurrence of bar if there are more than one bar.

But I was wondering, is it possible with sed or some other tool to actually find the previous occurrence of foo and keep a count. If it's not followed by a foo of its own, delete the bar. Like all the cases below.

1.(delete 1st bar)

```
bar
...
foo
foobar
bar
```

2.(delete 2nd bar because even though there is a foo before it, it's already counted for 1st bar)

```
foo
foobar
bar
...
bar
```

3.(delete 2nd and 4th bar)

```
foo
foobar
bar
...
bar
...
foo
bar
...
bar
```

Comment: Here: `foo \n text \n bar \n bar` do you want to delete both or keep the first?

Comment: No. Will keep the 1st one. It doesn't matter if any text is there or not in between foo and bar. But if bar is existing without foo, I want to delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '/^bar/{if (k) k=0; else next} /^foo/{k=1} 1' file
```

`k` means keep the line, it expires at first `bar` found after `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible with sed or some other tool to actually find the previous occurrence of foo and keep a count.

It is possible with `sed`, in principle, to keep a running count the number of appearances of `foo`.  For example, performing an `H` command for each `foo` line would do this, though the resulting count would be in a form that was a bit tricky to use.

But it sounds like you don't really need a *count* so much as you need a *flag* to report on whether any `foo`s have yet been seen.  For that, I would just use an `h` command.  An overall `sed` program to delete all `bar` lines that precede the first `foo` line, leaving all other lines unchanged, could look like this:

```
# When a 'foo' line is encountered, copy it to the hold space
/^foo$/ h
# If is a 'bar' then print or delete it, as appropriate
/^bar$/ {
# Append a newline and the contents of the hold space to the pattern space
G
# If the pattern space (now) ends in `foo`, then print up to the first newline of it
/foo$/ P
# delete the contents of the pattern space and start the next cycle
d
}
```

You can put that in a file and use `sed`'s `-f` option to read the commands from there, or you can put it directly on the command line by removing the comments and concatenating the lines with semicolon delimiters:

```
sed '/^foo$/ h; /^bar$/ {G; /foo$/ P; d; }' input > output
```

#### Update

Simpler, though, and clearer would be to express what you intend via an address range:

```
# For all lines from before the first through one containing foo
0,/^foo$/ {
# delete bar lines
/^bar$/ d
}
```

Or in a single command:

```
sed '0,/^foo$/ { /^bar$/ d; }' input > output
```

However, use of line number 0 as an address or in an address range may require GNU `sed`.  It definitely works with GNU `sed`, but POSIX specifications for `sed` do not clearly indicate that it is supported.

Comment: I like the idea of using sed because my awk doesn't support `-i`. And also like the way you have explained instead of just giving an answer. The sed command deletes all occurences of both foo and bar irrespective of their occurrence pattern (even the good ones). Lemme play around to find the right one. :)

Comment: My bad, @RatDon, I should have tested more carefully before posting.  I have updated the answer with working code along similar lines.  The problem with the original was that the `n` command doesn't do quite what I claimed -- it reads the next line, but *does not* automatically start the next cycle.

Comment: I didn't knew about the hold and pattern spaces before. Thanks for pointing that, learning them currenly. Regarding your answer, It still removes the good entries of bar along with the bad entries. e.g. bar \n... \n foo \n...\n bar. In this case both the bar is removed.

Comment: @RatDon, the test case you present is a bit unclear: are there trailing space characters on your lines?    Or do you perhaps have DOS line terminators? The sed code presented matches lines containing *exactly* `foo` or `bar`.  The regexes can be adjusted if you want to be more accommodating.  It works correctly for me if the lines have the form it is designed for.

Comment: I'm refering to the 1st test case in the question out of the 3. In my case, foobar contains trailing text. Which  I tried to incorporate in your answer with wildcard characters. But still it removed all the bar.